# MCollective Trigger Puppet agent from server failing

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache, mcollective, librarian-puppet

I'm using Puppet Opensource 4.6.1 with MCollective 2.9.0. I need to trigger the Puppet agent from the Puppet Master. However, I'm unable to find the `puppet runonce` command. Was this command deprecated, or is there a new command to trigger the Puppet agent from the puppet master.
`using Latest puppet opensource 2.6.0 and Mcollective 2.9.0`

Comment: `puppet runonce` is part of the rpc plugins for MCollective. You may want to check if MCollective was installed correctly.

Comment: @MattSchuchard This command was disappeared in Latest puppet opensource ver 2.6.0 and Mcollective 2.9.0